# GETX: how to create a RxList from GetStorage.read (error: 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<String>?' in type cast)

Tags: flutter

I have a 2 List like this:

```
var listStringRaw = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var listIntRaw = [1, 2, 3];
```

then write them to GetStorage:

```
  await GetStorage().write('listString', listStringRaw);
  await GetStorage().write('listInt', listIntRaw);
```

So how can I assign them to RxList in GetxController?

```
  RxList<String> get listString => GetStorage().read('listString') ?? [];
  RxList<int> get listInt => GetStorage().read('listInt') ?? [];
```

the error appears when I try:
`Unhandled Exception: type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<String>?' in type cast`

pls help me, this is the full code:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  var listStringRaw = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  var listIntRaw = [1, 2, 3];

  await GetStorage().write('listString', listStringRaw);
  await GetStorage().write('listInt', listIntRaw);

  Get.put(Controller());
}

class Controller extends GetxController {

  RxList<String> get listString => GetStorage().read('listString') ?? [];
  RxList<int> get listInt => GetStorage().read('listInt') ?? [];

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print(listString);
    print(listInt);
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read get package's doc, it says that you need to use the **.obs** method to convert anything to an Rx object.

```dart
RxList<String> get listString => (GetStorage().read<List<String>?>('listString') ?? []).obs;
  RxList<int> get listInt => (GetStorage().read<List<int>?>('listInt') ?? []).obs;
```

Also, the call to **read()** of GetStorage() has to be declared with the return type so that the compiler knows the object you will be working with.